# python numpy array search

Tags: python, numpy

Still learning about how to manipulate numpy array, any help is highly appreciated.

Here is the layout:

```
col1 coln index   cid  d1  d2  d3  d4
some vals  0       1    some values
           1       2   
           2       0
           3       1
           4       3
           5       1  
           6       0
           7       2
```

I want to find the lowest index associated with each cid and store it in a list. e.g. for cid 1 it would be 0, for cid 0 it would be 2, for cid it would be 1 and so on.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using pandas groupby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in numpy with something like the following.  Iterate over each unique CID and get the index to the first `True` in a list comprehension.    [np.unique()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) will give you all the values of CID.  [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) returns the index to the maximum value in an array.  If there are multiple of the same then it returns the first occurrence.  Therefore it will return the first index of `True` for each comparison.

```
import numpy as np
cid = np.array([1,2,0,1,3,1,0,2])
first_idx = [np.argmax(cid == x) for x in np.unique(cid)]
print(first_idx)
```

Results in:
[2, 0, 1, 4]

Comment: Thanks! That is a great solution! Out of curiosity, how did you learn Python? There are so many ways of doing the same thing, so many syntaxes, so many ready to use functions!